how to get rid of this warning "amssymb should not be used in conjunction with mbdch"
I am writing an article in East Asian J of Applied Mathematics. The preamble is
\documentclass{eajam}
%%%%% journal  info %%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand\thisnumber{x}
\renewcommand\thisyear {2024}
\renewcommand\thismonth{June}
.
\renewcommand\thisvolume{xx}
%%%%%%%%   end  %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

%%%%% author macros %%%%%%%%%
% place your own macros HERE
%%%%% end %%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

when I am running latex it shows warning as
"amssymb should not be used in conjunction with mbdch"
"amsfonts should not be used in conjunction with mbdch"
How can I overcome this problem.
Please help me out.

Welcome! You shouldn't change the fonts of an article you're submitting to a journal using their class/package because the journal will want your article to use the font setup they've designed. Or else they will substitute proprietary fonts before publication anyway. So just remove the charter lines.
